# file renaming/deleting

Tags: python, unix

I have a few files like this-

*.sss and  *_passive.sss

If I have a file called blah1.sss and blah1_passive.sss, i want to get rid of blah1.sss and rename blah1_passive.sss. However, if I don't have blah1_passive.sss I want to log the filename and keep blah1.sss.

I was able to locate all the *_passive.sss files but I would like to know the awk/sed etc command that could rename the *_passive.sss to *.sss.

Edit: Right now i have this but os.rename does not overwrite files, i need it to overwrite though.

```
import os, fnmatch

def locate(pattern, root=os.curdir):

    #ignore directories- uncomment to make ignore work
    #ignored = ["0201", "0306"]
  for path, dirs, files in os.walk(os.path.abspath(root)):
         #for dir in ignored:                  # if dir in dirs:                        #dirs.remove(dir)
    for filename in fnmatch.filter(files, pattern):
       yield os.path.join(path, filename)



for filename in locate("*_passive.sss"):
               #found the files that i want to rename, but os.rename() refuses to overwrite !! 
    newfilename=filename.rstrip("_passive.sss") + ".sss"
    os.rename(filename,newfilename)
```

Comment: Try `os.remove(newfilename); os.rename(filename,newfilename)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Unix you can use the following command in a Bourne shell (i.e. `sh`/`bash`):

```
for f in *_passive.sss; do mv -v $f `basename $f _passive.sss`.sss; done
```

Comment: @gregg: This will certainly work in *some* shells, but definitely not in others. @illusionist: your question was tagged Python, is the scripting language important, or do you just want to get the job done?

Comment: i'd love to get this in python, os.rename() would do the task for me but it does not over write the files.

Comment: I would quote file names to avoid problems if spaces in filenames

Comment: @Illusionist: with `os.rename` try deleting the file you want to overwrite first. Read docs: http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.rename

Comment: @Johnsyweb: Can you explain your portability concerns? All you need to run the command is a Bourne shell.

Comment: @Gregg: Not every Unix user has `bash` as their default shell. This will not work in `tcsh`, for instance.

Comment: @Johnsyweb: The command does not require `bash`, only `sh`, which is installed on most Unix systems. I agree that it will not work in `csh`/`tcsh`.

Answer (score 1):

This shell script shoul do the trick:

```
while read f; do
    fp="`echo "$f" | sed -nr 's|(.*)(\.sss)|\1_passive\2| p'`"
    if [ -f "$fp" ]; then mv "$fp" "$f"
    else  echo "file $fp missing" >> missing.log
    fi
done<<<"`ls -1 *.sss | grep -v _passive.sss`"
```

also will report missing `_passive` files to `missing.log`

Comment: thanks, willthis work in windows ? I tried running it with sh.exe and it told me "syntax error near unexpected token "done"

Comment: OMG why you tagged unix if you want it to run on Windows? It's a unix shell script and will work in all shells, AFAIK

Comment: @Illusionist: I never used sh.exe but I suppose he doesn't know how to handle a `<<<`  _here string_

Comment: It will do the trick if you start your script with `#!/usr/bin/env bash`!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a python solution:

```
import os
from glob import glob

# Write out test files.
with open('foo.sss', 'w'):  pass
with open('foo_passive.sss', 'w'):  pass
with open('bar.sss', 'w'):  pass

# Rename files.
files = glob('*.sss')
for filename in files:
  if filename.endswith('_passive.sss'):  continue
  passive_fname = filename.split('.sss')[0] + '_passive.sss'
  if passive_fname in files:
    os.remove(filename)
    os.rename(passive_fname, filename)
  else:
    print 'no passive: ', filename
```